# React Router dynamic pass down props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My goal is to pass a value from one component to another with the following code:  So let's say I'm at example.com/iamhere and I go to example.com/anotherpage I would like to pass the value of this.state.myProp to that other route.

I'm working on a project with some existing code and I have this:

```
getRoutes = routes => {
  return routes.map((prop, key) => {
    if (prop.layout === "/admin") {
      return (
    <Route
      path={prop.layout + prop.path}
      component={prop.component}
      key={key}
      myProp={this.state.myProp}
    />
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

I need to pass a prop down, just as an example something like this:

```
<Route
  path={prop.layout + prop.path}
  component={prop.component}
  key={key}
  myProp={this.state.myProp}
/>
```

Notice the addition of myProp I wish to pass this value to the next route it goes to.  According to a post on [git hub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-256932342).  It would be like I did above then in child route I'd use this.props.route.myProp.  However that doesn't work, it appears as undefined.

This has been suggested:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Component {...props} something={this.state.myProp}/>}/>
```

But how can I pass the dynamic route component listed in the above code to it?

Any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean "pass this value to the next route it goes to"? Can you explain a bit more what the desired behavior is?

Comment: @jered My goal is to pass a value from one component to another with the following code:  So let's say I'm at example.com/iamhere and I go to example.com/anotherpage I would like to pass the value of this.state.myProp to that other route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use React Router's `render` prop as opposed to `component`:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Component {...props} something={this.state.myProp}/>}/>
```

Comment: How would I achieve that with this dynamic render path?  component={prop.component} . @Rutherford Wonkington

Comment: Well to render the component from a map in any form you'd need to have an array of components which you can invoke with typical JSX syntax like above.

Comment: No problem.  It looks like you're storing components in an object? I've never actually done that, but theoretically as long as you're storing the component itself and not a string it should work.  Hope it works out!